# How to convert nested dictionary with variable string at each level into a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have an ordered dictionary that has a string on each sublevel for a variable and then a list of ordered dictionaries, with a new variable string introduced at each level.

So for example, the first level has the keys "DeliveryYear" and "DailyData", where "DeliveryYear" is 2021, and "DailyData is a list of ordered dictionaries. Clicking on any one of those ordered dictionaries under "DailyData" will give you 2 keys, in this case "Day" which is a string and then "HourlyData", which is another list of ordered dictionaries.

The dictionaries proceed like this until each variable has been assigned a string. I need to somehow turn the final string of each ordered dictionary into an entry in a data frame, with the strings in the dictionaries preceding it as columns.

So for example the goal output would be:

```
Year Day Hour Type ..... Value
2021  1   1    1         5000
2021  1   1    2         2000
2021  1   2    1         4000
2021  1   2    2          200
```

What kind of code would accomplish this in Python?

So far I have tried

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, 'index') for k, v in data.items()}, axis=0)
```

but I get this error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'" because of the strings at each subdictionary level.

Any help with this is immensely appreciated!

EDIT: The code that will get you the dictionary I'm referring to is:

```
import xmltodict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Set up Beautiful Soup for web scraping
url = "url"
r = requests.get(url)
soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

#Get first XML file on webpage (should be the most recent)
link=soup.select_one("a[href$='.xml']")['href']
prefix='http://website'
linkname=prefix+link
response = requests.get(linkname)

#Convert XML to ordered dictionary
data = (xmltodict.parse(response.content)['Document'])['DocBody']
```

Comment: if data is your dictionary data, can you try simply df  = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

Comment: @CutePanda the issue with doing that is then I only get the first level as a variable and then one column for "DailyData" which has a massive list (contents of the subdictionaries) for each row entry

Comment: Can you share the dictionary or some sample dictionary?

Comment: Sure I added the code that produces this dictionary to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can load and flatten the dictionary with [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict

response = requests.get("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly.xml")
data = (xmltodict.parse(response.content, dict_constructor=dict)['Document'])['DocBody'] # use dict_constructor=dict to load as regular dict instead of OrderedDict
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['DailyData', 'HourlyData', 'FuelTotal'], meta=['DeliveryYear', ['DailyData', 'Day'],['DailyData', 'HourlyData', 'Hour']], errors = "ignore") # record_path selects the list with the records that need to be put in rows, meta contains the other values that should be parsed in the rows
```

Output `df.head()`:

|  | Fuel | EnergyValue.OutputQuality | EnergyValue.Output | DeliveryYear | DailyData.Day | DailyData.HourlyData.Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NUCLEAR | 0 | 9021 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | GAS | -1 | 338 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | HYDRO | 0 | 4781 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 3 | WIND | 0 | 161 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 4 | SOLAR | 0 | 0 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find some easy to implement way but it seems manually traversing through data is the only option.

```
import xmltodict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Set up Beautiful Soup for web scraping
url = "http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/?fbclid=IwAR2VNDIaCYdCFodq5ZQCz63pBcSwEgANea-UFyAX-qj2VGofinhSv6PKTE4"
r = requests.get(url)
soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

#Get first XML file on webpage (should be the most recent)
link=soup.select_one("a[href$='.xml']")['href']
prefix='http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/'
linkname=prefix+link
response = requests.get(linkname)

#Convert XML to ordered dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DeliveryYear', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Fuel', 'OutputQuality', 'Output'])
data = (xmltodict.parse(response.content)['Document'])['DocBody']
data_list = [data]

for n1 in data_list:
    o1 = n1['DeliveryYear']
    a = n1['DailyData']
    for n2 in a:
         o2 = n2['Day']
         b = n2['HourlyData']
         for n3 in b:
             o3 = n3['Hour']
             c = n3['FuelTotal']
             for n4 in c:
                 o4 = n4['Fuel']
                 d = n4['EnergyValue']
                 o5 = d['OutputQuality']
                 o6 = d['Output']
                 df.loc[len(df.index)] = [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6]
df
```

This code returns the desired results. As the number of rows is high, it will take some time to return the result.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function that 'probes' the `data` list and creates a new linear list of dictionaries each one representing a single document with all the keys collected on the 'path' to the final value.

Basically the function would perform the following steps for each dictionary in the `data` list:

1. Build a new empty dictionary `entry`
2. Check if `doc` (*i*-th dictionary in data) contains any *list* type. If no *list* were found, all its *key:value* pairs are added to `entry`. This is where the 'path' to the final value ends, and `entry` is ultimately appended to the main list of `entries`.
3. If the dictionary contains at least one *list*, the same tasks are performed until the list is found, at which point the function calls itself recursively with that list as the new data parameter.
4. At the end of all the iterations, the main list of documents `entries` is returned.

The following example kind of shows better what I'm trying to explain:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def probeDict(data, entry={}, entries=[]):
    for doc in data:
        if not any([isinstance(v, list) for v in doc.values()]): #Is there any list?
            for k,v in doc.items():
                entry[k] = v #If it's not a list, add it to the entry dictionary.
            entries.append(deepcopy(entry)) #deepcopy because entry dicts cannot be shallow copies of each other.
            entry = {} #Emptying entry for the next set of recursions.
        else:
            for k,v in list(doc.items()):
                if not isinstance(v, list):
                    entry[k] = v
            else:
                probeDict(v, entry, entries) #If value is a list, recall probeDict with this value as data argument.
    return entries
```

So, for instance, running this with the following `data` list:

```
>>> data = [
              {"DeliveryYear":2021, 
               "DailyData":[
                              {"Day":1, 
                               "HourlyData":[
                                               {"Type":1}
                                            ]
                              }, 
                              {"Day":2, 
                               "HourlyData":[
                                               {"Type":2}
                                            ]
                              }
                           ]
              }
           ]

>>> probeDict(data)
```

Would print out this:

```
>>> [{'DeliveryYear': 2021, 'Day': 1, 'Type': 1}, {'DeliveryYear': 2021, 'Day': 2, 'Type': 2}]
```

Then you can easily build the dataframe from this new list.